# Is Kullback Liebler Divergence already implented in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, data-loss

I am working with tensorflow and using Nueral Networks to solve multi-label classification problem. I was using Softmax cross entropy as my loss function:

```
#Softmax loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
```

Now, i thought that i should use KL divergence loss function. But, i didn't find it in tensorflow can any body help me to use KL Divergence loss function instead of Softmax loss?

Comment: KL divergence measures the difference between two probability distributions. How is this related to a multi-label loss function? Or in other words, what is exactly a KL Divergence loss? [Torch](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md) (similar to tensorflow) has the KL implemented, but as I mentioned, only for fitting continuous probability distributions.

Comment: These are example 'x' labels, TrueLabel = [1, 0, 0, 1] and PredLabel= [0.95, 0, 0, 0.99]. I want to minimize the distance between the actual:[1,0,0,1] and pred: [0.95, 0, 0, 0.99]  to occur at the same time for a specific example. In other words i want to minimize the distance pred and actual multi labels  to occur at the same time.

Comment: There is a post in the first [entry after googling it](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/TX32t7NHkpA). There you can find how to implement the KL Divergence in tensorflow. However, I have the impression that it is not what you are looking for. Either that, or your example in the question is very unrelated to what you try to achieve.

Comment: I saw this post and implemented already implemented it. But, i was looking to use some built in function of tensor flow. Because it might not be the correct implementation i doubt

Comment: I was using Softmax regression and the results of KL divergence is  not much different...

Comment: Softmax cross entropy is the KL divergence loss

Comment: So, it means KL is exactly the same loss function as cross entropy? Means it doesn't have any effect wether use KL divergence or Softmax cross entropy?

Comment: yes, they are the same

Comment: Reviving an old thread here, but AFAIU, cross entropy = entropy + KL divergence.  So KL divergence = cross entropy - entropy.

Comment: True what MiniQuark said. If p (labels) is constant, then obviously you won't need the entropy term. But if you have two nonconstant distributions in the graph, you need the full KL-divergence...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
tf.contrib.distributions.kl(distribution_1, distribution_2)
```

Comment: I looked at the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d24e64227653ab3cab7405c79ca166063a42f0ff/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/kullback_leibler.py), but it seems that the set _DIVERGENCES is empty (so it seems the function is not fully implemented...). I get an error `TypeError: dist_a is not an instance of Distribution...` when trying that out with softmax...